# Points to GPX: Creating waypoints in QGIS for use in GPS

Tags: qgis, point, convert, gpx

I'm wanting to create and export GPX point data in QGIS, to subsequently load it into my GPS.

I started off by creating a `New Shapefile Layer` with geometry type 'Point'. The fields list contains one attribute called 'name' which is text data. I create a few points, give each point a name and save the layer.

To export as GPX, I did the following:

1. *Export > Save Feature As*
2. Format as GPX, with *GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS* as 'YES'

It is able to successfully make a new GPX layer within QGIS, as well as save. However, it seems like I missed a step as the converted waypoints do not visually appear in QGIS, and BaseCamp cannot import it.

Any suggestions? The attribute table of the new layer seems to be missing coordinate data, but my understanding is that exporting as GPX was meant to fill in all the blanks. I can also still 'zoom to layer', even though it isn't plotting the new GPX layer.

I'm using QGIS 3.8.1 Zanzibar

Comment: can you show the content of the GPX file you created in the question.

Comment: Using the GPS plugin might expand on what your doing, it has more functionality https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html (including waypoints).